accessing dependency property between viewmodels
I have 2 viewmodels say,
viewmodel is bound to view
class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public A(){}

private bool _propertya;
public bool PropertyA
{
get{return _propertya;}
set{_propertya=value; onPropertyChanged("PropertyA");}
}

private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

And another viewmodel where my properties are linked to another view
class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public B(){}

private bool _propertyb;
public bool PropertyB
{
get{ return _propertyb;}
set{_propertyb=value; onPropertyChanged("PropertyB");}
}
private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

When PropertyB is changed , I want to check the value of PropertyA from another viewmodel and return bool value based on condition. How can i get the instance of PropertyA from another viewmodel in class B

There are many solutions depending on the design, is A and B on the same Level or B child of A

I think there are many possible solutions. a) I think it's clean if B depends on data PropertyA that B should also have a member PropertyA that is also bound to the view. b) Or view model class A sends the data of PropertyA to the model. Then the view model class B can query that data from the model. c) Or related logic in class B should really be in class A as this data envy(?) could be a hint that you chose the wrong encapsulation strategy. d) Or you should use composition/aggregation to enable B to use A. What is best really depends on the context or semantics.

If the data of PropertyA is application data, then you should avoid the coupling between A and B and let B get the data via the model instead. Otherwise, anything is possible. It really depends on the details.

Agree BionicCode

It seems like you are searching for a solution to have some sort of global/shared state. This state can than be used by different classes like the view models. I don't know how you've designed parts like navigation but I would suggest to use dependency injection and a singleton for this.
If you are not familiar with dependency injection, in essence it makes it possible to inject a class and their responsibilities into another class. For example I got a class with a global state called DataContext, I want to use this class across multiple view models or models. I can inject the DataContext into said view models by using the constructor. For example:
    public class DataContext {}

    public class ViewModel {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public ViewModel(DataContext context) {
            _context = context;
        }
    }

The DataContext will be a singleton, meaning for dependency injection only one instance will be used. To use dependency injection in your WPF application, packages such as Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection can be used. In the App.xaml.cs, initialization of dependency injection can be done by using the Startup event of the application. For example:
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<MainWindow>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DataContext>();

    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Show();
}

Adding the MainWindow as a transient is needed to make the dependency injection work (I believe, but I'm not 100% sure of that). More information about dependency injection and WPF can be found here. This might seem overwhelming but I think this is a very good approach to solve your issue. Hope it helps :)

General Solution (Using EventArgs)
*** Important note from @Clemens ***

Using static classes in view models is generally a bad idea. It would be far simpler when an instance of B would know the associated instance of A and directly register a handler for A's PropertyChanged event


Changes:

Create SharedClass For Test Only (its content should be moved to class A or kept in the case of A is Singleton)
SharedClass.UpdatePropertyA(new SharedClass.PropertyA_EventArgs()...
SharedClass.PropertyAChanged += SharedClass_PropertyAChanged;
private void SharedClass_PropertyAChanged(object? sender, SharedClass.PropertyA_EventArgs e)


public static class SharedClass
{
    public class PropertyA_EventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool PropertyA_OldValue { get; set; }
        public bool PropertyA_NewValue { get; set; }
    }
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyA_EventArgs> PropertyAChanged;
    public static void UpdatePropertyA(PropertyA_EventArgs PropertyA_Event)
    {
        PropertyAChanged?.Invoke(null, PropertyA_Event);
    }
}


public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public A() { }

    private bool _propertya;
    public bool PropertyA
    {
        get { return _propertya; }
        set
        {
        // ----------------------------------
            SharedClass.UpdatePropertyA(
            new SharedClass.PropertyA_EventArgs()             
            {    
                PropertyA_OldValue = _propertya,         
                PropertyA_NewValue = value
            });
        // ----------------------------------
            _propertya = value; onPropertyChanged("PropertyA");
        }
    }

    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public B()
    {
    // ----------------------------------
        SharedClass.PropertyAChanged += SharedClass_PropertyAChanged;
    // ----------------------------------
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    private void SharedClass_PropertyAChanged(object? sender, SharedClass.PropertyA_EventArgs e)
    {
        //Usage : 
        // To Access Old Value: e.PropertyA_OldValue
        // To Access New Value: e.PropertyA_NewValue
        //...
    }
    // ----------------------------------

    private bool _propertyb;
    public bool PropertyB
    {
        get { return _propertyb; }
        set { _propertyb = value; onPropertyChanged("PropertyB"); }
    }
    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


The static class is still bad design. What happens when you have more than one instance of A and B? And why don't you edit your other answer instead of writing a new one? Or at least delete the other answer.

I kept the old answer to preserve your useful comment as a guide, I will remove it. Am still using static because the OP not replied yet to our comments, to explain his design.  Thanks!
